# Does python identify critical section automatically?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am new to Python multithreading coding. I consult the manual for Lock Object usage and find the normal case is

```
g_mutex = Lock()
g_mutex.acquire()
#some code
g_mutex.release()
```

But the lock does not specify what variable or function it is going to lock? So does python automatically find all critical variables to be locked? What if I call some function to modify some variables?

Comment: Multithreaded code, especially using locks, can cause multiple sleepless nights. I would be beware to read some parallel programming books first.

Comment: @phaedrus Could you recommend some?

Comment: This looks good: http://www.dailymotion.com/playlist/x1pc0m_Intel_Academic_EMEA_intro-to-parallel-programming/1#videoId=xksoje

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of a `Lock` is that at most one thread can hold it at any given time.  If you acquire the lock, you can be sure no other process holds it.  It's up to you to define the semantics of the lock -- if you want to use it to guard the access to some variable, just do so: acquire the lock before messing around with that variable, release it when you are done.  There is no need for an explicit relation between the lock object and the variable it protects -- this is defined by the way you use it.  (Also note that there is nothing Python-specific to this concept.)

Answer (score 0):

Lock will not found variables or functions to lock. Lock is a mecanism that you can use to do so. For example, if you want to protect the variable `foo` of any modification, you must:

- create a lock for that variable
- acquire before any modification or usage in your whole code
- release after

Comment: So how to **create a lock for a variable** in Python? Could you give some code?

Comment: You wrote it in your question, that's exactly the same :)